# Limiting total Core file sizes to 10% of disk usage in ArchLinux

Tags: linux, archlinux, coredump

I need to limit the total core files sizes generated to be 10% of my disk usage. I have set ulimit -c to be unlimited stating that each file size is unlimited. Then I used the configuration file
/etc/systemd/coredump.conf.d/custom.conf to set

```
[Coredump]
Storage=external
#Compress=yes
#ProcessSizeMax=2G
#ExternalSizeMax=2G
#JournalSizeMax=767M
MaxUse=10
#KeepFree=15
```

I thought this configuration file will limit the disk usage to 10%. But still the core file usage exceeds 10%.

I tried setting the Storage=none ., Still I got the core files generated. Setting the ulimit -c to 0., stopped generating core files. But I want the disk usage to be 10%.

Comment: would a partial `core` file be of any use? How big (percent-wize and MB/GB-size) are the current core files that you get? Not sure this is really a programming Q suitable for S.O., but you don't have any close votes yet. Good luck.

Comment: This really belongs on serverfault or the Unix and Linux stack exchange site.